# PHP Template include() causing directory errors

Tags: php, html, css, include, image

I have been having this issue when I use the php `include()` or `require()` function. I will try and explain it as best as possible down here but let me know if it does not make sense. I am building a theme system where the main `index.php` has `include ('themes/main/header.php')` but there are errors when linking stylesheets and images. Here is how my directory is set out.

- htdocs

  - index.php
  - themes
  - - main
  - - - header.php
  - - - footer.php
  - - - images
  - - - css
  - - - js

Here is the contents of my header.php (striped):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

When I load up the main index.php the stylesheet and images are not able to be found. I know this is because the header file is brought into the index.php file but is there a way around this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, for myself, use something like this:

```
define(SITE_ROOT, '/'); //client side root of website
define(SITE_PATH, '/var/www/mywebsite/htdocs/'); //serverside root of website 

function url($relative, $startingFrom = false, $echo = true) {
    $r = '';
    if($startingFrom === false) {
        $r = SITE_ROOT . $relative;
    } else {
        $forward = str_replace('\\', '/', $startingFrom);
        $path = substr($forward, 0, strrpos($forward, '/'));
        $r = SITE_ROOT . substr($path, strlen(SITE_PATH)) . '/' . $relative;
    }
    if($echo) {
        echo $r;
    } else {
        return $r;
    }
}
```

in short, this builds a "site absolute" path for you, this way you could also change the name of your "theme" without having to change all absolute references it contains.

this way, in `header.php` you can write:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php url('css/layout.css', __FILE__);?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

the function has several optional attributes, they should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's include is (being in PHP) on the server side, but the references in the HTML file are client-side, so they refer to their perceived file (index.php). Simply adjust the path in the file to accomodate.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a 'template_path' variable to your template files and pass that variable to your template parser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{TEMPLATE_PATH}css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<img src="{TEMPLATE_PATH}images/logo.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. How do I define {TEMPLATE_PATH}

Comment: I assume that you use some kind of template engine. So {TEMPLATE_PATH} is the template engine variable and when initializing the template engine you pass there some variable like `$templatePath = '/themes/main/';`
And then the template engine replaces engine variables like: 

`$search = array("{TEMPLATE_PATH}");
$replace = array($templatePath);
$newphrase = str_replace($search, $replace, $template);`

It's just a principle, not exact realization.

Answer (score 0):

including file in php is not cutting the path for browser, in html it should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/main/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Ok. I was looking for something like the wordpress system. Do you know how that works?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is done in wordpress but you can create php file that reade css files and return content with modified headers. This file can be located in main folder under name css.php and it will read and return css files from theme.

Answer (score 0):

i made an edit after rereading your questions to - change your paths to be like this:

```
href="/themes/main/css/layout.css" 
src="/themes/main/images/logo.png"
```

this should resolve it, but you should consider using 'http' absolute paths as a best practice. i hope it helps.

Comment: using 'http' absolute paths is a worst practice though. why do you think it can help?

Comment: wow, first you compliment me, then you backhand me; not sure what's going on here.  it's been my experience that caching happens more often with full "http" paths, especially with proxies, also, i generally like having my styles keep on pages where you view source.

Comment: it has nothing to do with proxies. just because there is no such thing like URL beside the browser's address bar. The HTTP request contains only path, without http and without domain name. So, through proxy goes the SAME request for both cases.

Answer (score -1):

There's usually two options:

- First, use absolute URLs (i.e. full URLs including `http://.../css/layout.css` or simply only the path from root, e.g. `/themes/main/css/layout.css`)
- Second, build a relative path from the 'main' file where you include your other files from. In this case, that would be `/themes/main/css/layout.css`.

Comment: Yours are good intentions but the phrasing is different from them

Comment: Eh what? Using absolute paths is the best one could do. They will work form whatever file/include one desires. How is this not in line with what the topic poster wanted to know?

Comment: absolute paths - yes, not full urls as in your example. addressing your own site with full http url makes no sense. absolute path is enough. relative paths created from whatever file is not an option. always use absolute paths from the site root.

Comment: Hmm ok. Makes sense that the http://domain.com can be omitted (i.e. it is more concise without it), but are there any other reasons to not include the domain name?

Comment: @WillemMulder: Portability. For example using the same code for developing, testing and prodution.

Comment: There are many people that recommend you use the full URL for SEO. There is no harm in it. It can only help you. If you store the domain in a variable, you just have to change it once if you are moving your code around.

Comment: @LoganSerman: That's my thoughts exactly. You generate the URLs yourself, based on the current host-name, so the URLs are always correct (i.e. also in different environments). That is, when we can assume that generated html and caches are saved on a per-domain basis.

Comment: @LoganSerman who are these people and what are their reasons? And why no big site is using it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your file names in reference to `index.php`. Another way to get around this is to declare some variables in a configuration file (or in a small project like this, just in `index.php`) that contains your full website URL:

`$site = http://www.example.com/`

And then use this for all of your css, links, scripts, etc references. This way it will be an absolute path. Then you can do something like:

`<img src="<?= $site ?>images/logo.png" />`

If I'm not mistaken I think using absolute paths is better for SEO (search-engine optimization).